# Are GetCallingAssembly() and GetExecutingAssembly() equally prone to JIT inlining?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, jit

There's [Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx) and [Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly.aspx). Note that `GetCallingAssembly()` has a `Remark` mentioning that depending on how JIT inlining behaves it may be possible that one method is (or is not) inlined into another and so `GetCallingAssembly()` returns varying results.

Now how is `GetExecutingAssembly()` different? JIT inlining could technically inline the code that calls `GetExecutingAssembly()` and so that code now belongs to a different assembly and depending on whether that happened `GetExecutingAssembly()` can just as well produce varying results.

Why doesn't `GetExecutingAssembly()` description have remarks mentioning JIT inining similar to what `GetCallingAssembly()` description has?

Comment: It is of course one possibility that both are susceptible, and the comment should apply equally to both.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `GetExecutingAssembly` method is not susceptible to JIT inlining because of the same reason `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod` is also not susceptible since they are implemented in a similar way.

Both methods declare a local variable of a special enumeration `StackCrawlMark` and initialize it to `StackCrawlMark.LookForMyCaller`. This local variable has the side effect of preventing the method calling into `GetExecutingAssembly` or `GetCurrentMethod` from being inlined which will then guarantee correct results.

This is supported by experimentation and also by the comment associated with this enumeration in the SSCLI20:

```
// declaring a local var of this enum type and passing it by ref 
// into a function that needs to do a stack crawl will both prevent inlining of 
// the calle and pass an ESP point to stack crawl to
//
// Declaring these in EH clauses is illegal; 
// they must declared in the main method body
```

The reason `GetCallingAssembly` is susceptible is because you're looking for the caller's caller and the local variable only guarantees that the caller is **not** inlined, which means that the grandparent method can be inlined leading to an unexpected result.

Comment: That would be a breaking change so I would have to say no. I went through the technical implementation details only to support the fact that a method that calls `GetExecutingAssembly` is guaranteed to not be inlined and that's why the warning is not present in its documentation.