# Why has my function to display a help file (chm) suddenly stopped working?

Tags: c#, vsto, chm

I have a VSTO add in for Outlook written in C# that has a button to display a chm help file that has been working fine for a couple of years, and suddenly stopped working. When I click the button that runs the following code, nothing happens,

```
try
{
    string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase), "ema.chm");

    // Show the help.
    Help.ShowHelp(null, path);
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas what may cause a problem like that?

Comment: does the line containing `ShowHelp()` function get hit when debugging?

Comment: Maybe there was a change in the environment? Missing CHM file? Different assembly location?

Comment: Has the path of the helpfile moved perhaps?

Comment: No, I checked to see if the chm file is there, and it is, and nothing has changed with regard to the assembly location.

Comment: Use Assembly.Location, not CodeBase.

Comment: @Okuma.Scott - Yes, when I run it in debug the line with the ShowHelp() call does get executed.  Actually, I'm running in debug on a Win 7 machine that has Visual Studio 2010 installed on it (VSTO isn't supported in Visual Studio 2013) and it works fine on that machine.  It doesn't work on my Windows 8 machine, and to complicate matters further, I know of at least one user that is having this problem on his Windows 7 machine.

Comment: So it was working on Windows 8, but now it's not? Or it never worked on Windows 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two potential problems.

**1)** The way you are building `path` is not reliable.
There are [many ways to get a path](http://dailydotnettips.com/2013/10/29/different-ways-of-getting-path/), and they are not all created equal.
For example, [GetCallingAssembly is susceptible to JIT inlining](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12669945/2596334) which may produce varying results.
But I believe the real issue was hinted at by Hans already.
Try using a different way to build your path.
For example, [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/283917/2596334).

Here is an example of the way I usually get the path of a file in the assembly directory using a property:

```
    private string myXMLFile()
    {
        string ExecutingPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        return ExecutingPath + "MyFile.XML";
    }
```

Then it's easy to use it like this:

```
if (File.Exists(myXMLFile) == false) { CreateNewXMLFile(); }
XDocument Xdoc = XDocument.Load(myXMLFile);
...
Xdoc.Save(myXMLFile);
```

**2)** .CHM format may be blocked by Windows for "security" reasons.
It can be unblocked however, which leads to it working on some systems but not on others.
See [Windows 8 64bit can't open chm files](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-files/windows-8-64bit-cant-open-chm-files/7dec5d51-f621-4753-ab13-ea3b59a07cb8)

Comment: #Okuma.Scott - It turned out that the problem was caused by a change we had incorporated a while back to install the dll's in the GAC.  Out code was broken since the chm file was not in the GAC.  I switched the code to use your "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory: code above to get the directory for the program in Program Files, and it's working fine now.  I'm marking you answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If it's really true nothing changed and working for years hh.dat may cause a error.

The hh.dat file stores user-specific information on all the HTMLHelp files (*.CHM) on your system (position, favourite topics, search history, etc.), and may cause a error if it has somehow been corrupted.

Delete or rename the file hh.dat to reset all (!) CHM windows on your system to their default settings.  Windows will create a new version of hh.dat when you next open any .chm file. You should find hh.dat at:

Windows XP: \Documents and Settings\%username%\Application Data\Microsoft\HTML Help

Windows  7: \Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\HTML Help